# how to read an incomplete file and wait for new data in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a UDP client that grabs some data from another source and writes it to a file on the server. Since this is large amount of data, I dont want the end user to wait until they its full written to the server so that they can download it. So I made a NodeJS server that grabs the latest data from the file and sends it to the user.

Here is the code:

```
var stream = fs.readFileSync(filename)
    .on("data", function(data) {

         response.write(data)

    });
```

The problem here is, if the download starts when the file was only for example 10mb.. the fs.readFileSync will only read my file up to 10mb. Even if 2 mins later the file increased to 100mb. fs.readFileSync will never know about the new updated data. How can I do this in Node? I would like somehow refresh the fs state or maybe perpaps wait for new data using fs file system. Or is there some kind of fs fileContent watcher?

EDIT:

I think the code below describes better what I would like to achieve, however in this code it keeps reading forever and I dont have any variable from fs.read that can help me stop it:

```
fs.open(filename, 'r', function(err, fd) {
    var bufferSize=1000,
    chunkSize=512,
    buffer=new Buffer(bufferSize),
    bytesRead = 0;


    while(true){ //check if file has new content inside

        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, chunkSize, bytesRead);
        bytesRead+= buffer.length;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Node has built-in methods in the fs module. It is tagged as unstable, so it can change in the future.

Its called: `fs.watchFile(filename[, options], listener)`

You can read more about it here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener

But i highly suggest you to use one of the good modules mantained actively like 
**watchr**:

From his readme:

> Better file system watching for Node.js. Provides a normalised API the
>   file watching APIs of different node versions, nested/recursive file
>   and directory watching, and accurate detailed events for
>   file/directory changes, deletions and creations.

The module page is here: https://github.com/bevry/watchr

*(Used the module in a couple of proyects and working great, im not related to it in other way)*

Comment: Thanks but its still not exactly what I was looking for, I updated my question maybe it helps to understand more what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

you need store in some data base last size of file.
read filesize first.
load your file.
then make a script to check if file was change.
you can consult the size with jquery.post  to obtain your result and decide if need to reload in javascript